# Link to autofill an input box in another page

Tags: html

I'm trying to create a link that when clicked on will redirect me to another html page with a contact form, and in that form there is a subject input box. Depending on which link is clicked, I want the subject box to be populated with the corresponding link title.

Tried searching for awhile now and have no idea how to get it to work. Tried playing around with the key value pairs method mentioned in some other places but definitely doing it wrong, and not sure how.

Below is a snippet of my code. The h3 "Title of the product here" is what I want to populate the subject box with (in my actual website I will have multiple links populating the subject lines with different words).

**Main Page**

```
<div class="squareIndexContentBox1" style="background-color: #fff">
    <a href="contact us.html?subject=testing">
        <h3>Title of the product here</h3>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </p>
        <div class="learn-more">
            <span id="learn-more">Contact us</span>
            <span class="fa fa-hand-o-left"></span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**Page where I want the input box to be filled**

```
<div class="contact-form">
    <h2> Contact Us </h2>

    <form method="POST" action="contact-form-handler.php">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
        <br>

        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <br>

        <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
        <br>

        <textarea type="text" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        <br>

        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
        <br>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit-btn" value="Send Message">
    </form>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you navigate from main page to second page.

If you are using simple button to navigate to another page then pass the **unique field name** with button in url them use $_GET to get that variable and search specific fields in database with the help of that unique field and fill you inputs.

Secondly if you are navigating from main page to another page by clicking a submit button i.e. after filling some form then you can pass you **unique field name** by adding input type hidden to another page.

Example

```
First Example:  <a href="second_page.php?prop_id=5 ">Click </a>
```

> Get this variable(prop_id) in second_page with the help of $_GET

```
Second Example: <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="<?php echo $email_address;?>" >
```

> Now by submitting the form this input type also send to other page.

Or you can pass that unique field to another page by using **session**.

*****Unique Field name is the key through which you can easily find values from database.

Comment: thanks for the response. Sorry I don't get you, what do you mean by database? But yes, I'm using a simple link to redirect to a page with a form where I want an input field to be filled with some predefined text.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work using some js/jquery, though its a bit longer than what I think it could be. Also the problem with this is that the input box is automatically filled even if I go to the page without clicking onto either of the 4 specified links (through a navbar for example).

**Main Page**

```
        <div class="squareIndexContentBox1" style="background-color: #fff">
            <a href="contact us.html" onclick="autoinput1()">
                <h3 id="this1">Service 1</h3>
                <p>
                    dummy text 
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="squareIndexContentBox1" style="background-color: lightgrey;">
            <a href="contact us.html" onclick="autoinput2()">
                <h3 id="this2">Service 2</h3>
                <p>
                    dummy text  
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="squareIndexContentBox1" style="background-color: lightgrey;">
            <a href="contact us.html" onclick="autoinput3()"> 
                <h3 id="this3">Service 3</h3>
                <p>
                    dummy text 
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="squareIndexContentBox1" style="background-color: #fff">
            <a href="contact us.html" onclick="autoinput4()"> 
                <h3 id="this4">Service 4</h3>
                <p>
                    dummy text 
                </p>
            </a>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

Stores the product name as a variable that can be used across html files

```
function autoinput1() {
  var productName = document.getElementById('this1').innerText;
  localStorage.something = productName;
}

function autoinput2() {
  var productName = document.getElementById('this2').innerText;
  localStorage.something = productName;
}

function autoinput3() {
  var productName = document.getElementById('this3').innerText;
  localStorage.something = productName;
}

function autoinput4() {
  var productName = document.getElementById('this4').innerText;
  localStorage.something = productName;
}
```

Page where I want the input box to be filled.

Added some jQuery to fill up the "subject" input field based on the link clicked

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#subject").val(localStorage.something);
    });
</script>
```

In no way shape or form am I saying this is a good solution to my question, it's just the only way I can figure out. Even the code is extremely inefficient but I'm still just trying to learn ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Any other solutions are greatly appreciated :)

(or even just shortening my code)